# Get data from realtime db in firebase using a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I want to take data from realtime db using a variable using react js.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPNaS.jpg)

I tried all possible ways

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the data using onSnapshot, and also you can ensure that the data is updated when changes occur. There are examples here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen